# How to customize url/slug in laravel post

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to make my website slug/url be like this `localhost:8000/apartment/example-post-cat-come` instead of `localhost:8000/example-post-cat-come`

I have categories like 
1. Apartment
2. Flat

i want to add the post category before the slug in the url

currently i am doing this

```
Route::get('/{post}','ShowPropertiesController@index')->name('posts.show');
```

i also did the following after trying with the first route

```
Route::get('{category}/{post}','ShowPropertiesController@index')->name('posts.show');
```

and did this in my controller

```
public function index($category, $post)
{
    // ...
}
```

i got this error `Missing required parameters for [Route: posts.show] [URI: {category}/{post}]. (View: C:\MAMP\htdocs\laravel-real-estate\resources\views\pages\welcome.blade.php)`
This is my blade

```
<a href="{{ route('posts.show',$properties->slug) }}">{{$properties->title}}</a>
```

How can i make the category show before url?

Comment: why you can't remove the first route if the second is equivalent (for your description)?

Comment: i think that problem is in `welcome.blade.php`, looks like you forgot to pass parameters to named route

Comment: i have removed it that was when i got this error ```Missing required parameters for [Route: posts.show] [URI: {category}/{post}]. (View: C:\MAMP\htdocs\laravel-real-estate\resources\views\pages\welcome.blade.php) ```

Comment: @RainDev this is my blade ```<a href="{{ route('posts.show',$properties->slug) }}">{{$properties->title}}</a>```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in welcome.blade.php, you should pass all required parameters to route:

```
<a href="{{ route('posts.show',['category' => CATEGORY, 'post' => POST]) }}">{{$properties->title}}</a>
```

change CATEGORY and POST with your values

Comment: it is showing like this ```localhost:8000/Apartment/example-post``` but how can i change the A in Apartment to small letter `a` like this ```localhost:8000/apartment/example-post```

Comment: maybe you can use php function `['category' => strtolower(CATEGORY)] ` ?